# absolute value in derivative of inverse hyperbolic cosecant

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function, hyperbolic-functions

derivative of inverse hyperbolic cosecant is:

$$\frac {-1} {|x|\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

i saw in some website the absolute value of $x$ (in denominator) obtained after considering both $x>0$ and $x<0$. but, i don't have idea how.
here i'll attach result from both cases

when $x>0$ the derivative :
$$\frac {-1} {x\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

when $x<0$ the derivative :
$$\frac {1} {x\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

first,how both can turn into the general function (most top function that give x an absolute value) ?

second, i saw derivative of inverse hyperbolic secant, and it done by similiar ways, but absolute value is nowhere to be found. how ? thankyou in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is because
$$\text{csch}^{-1}(-x)=-\text{csch}^{-1}(x)$$
On the other side, in the real domain, $\text{sech}^{-1}(x)$ is undefined.

Comment: could you please also help me for second question?

Comment: @pikarin-g. May be, you could start with $x=\text{sech}(y)$, compute $x'$ and then $y'=\frac 1{x'}$ and use a few identities. Do it, it is not hard. If you are really lazy, have a look at https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Supplemental_Modules_(Calculus)/Integral_Calculus/4%3A_Transcendental_Functions/4.9%3A_Hyperbolic_Functions/Derivative_of_arcsech